# Prove or disprove: If $\sum{a_n}$ with $a_n>0$ is convergent then $\sum{a_n^2}$ is always convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So that's the question. But I am unable to find a counter example if it's false. Or how should I proceed to prove if it is true? I am confused please help. Many thanks.

Comment: Hint: for large enough $n$, $a_n^2 < a_n$

Comment: If $\sum a_n$ is convergent, then $a_n<1$ for large enough $n$, so $a_n^2<a_n$, so it converges by domination.

Comment: Oh didn't see that. Thank you guys.

Comment: Note: They specify that $a_n > 0$ because of alternating series like $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$. It converges, but if you square every term, you get the harmonic series, which does not converge.

Comment: Oh yes that's true. Good point @Arthur

Comment: Notice that since terms $a_{n}$ are positive it follows that $\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_{i}^{2}\leq (\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_{i})^{2}$. Since $\sum a_{n}$ converges it follows that partial sums of $\sum a_{n}^{2}$ are bounded therefore it is convergent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\sum a_n$ converges, then $0<a_n<1$ when $n$ is large (divergent test), then $0 < a_n^2 <a_n$ ($a_n >0$ is used) and one can conclude by comparison test.